# Recover line where a sequence of consecutive positive numbers are found in a vectors

Tags: python-3.x

With this python code, I am able to count sequences of positive number in a column.
Now I am trying to recover the line where these sequences are situated.

```
import numpy  as np
from itertools import groupby
data = np.loadtxt("Krin_yaoun.txt")
nlin, ncol = np.shape(data)
series = data[:, 0]
xx  = []
yy  = []
for k, g in groupby(series, key=lambda i: i > 0):
    sub_list = list(g)
 
    a = float(np.sum(sub_list))
    if a > 0: 
        xx.append(a)
        yy.append(len(sub_list))
        
        print(tuple(sub_list))
```

Comment: In which format do you need the positions of the sequences? You could for example also store the lengths of the sub_lists that don't match `a>0` and then by just testing the first element of `series`, you can construct the order and lengths of the sequences. There might be better ways, though, depending on what you want to do after.

Comment: Than you David
I added followind line to my script

    `np.where((series == tuple(sub_list)).all(1))[0]`

But I get this error

**count_positive_seq.py:84: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  np.where((series == tuple(sub_list)).all(1))[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_positive_seq.py", line 84, in <module>
    np.where((series == tuple(sub_list)).all(1))[0]
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'**

Comment: Normally, it would be nice to have the **first and last index**  of each sequence. 
In such a way i can easily identify which event is present in the different sequence. 

I am working with rainfall data and i am trying to identify wet spell. 
At the same time i want to know which days correspond to the different wet sequences

Comment: Happy my answer helps. Please consider accepting it if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of each sequence with positive entries:

```
pos = 0
for k, g in groupby(series, key=lambda i: i > 0):
    sub_list = list(g)
    L = len(sub_list)
    a = float(np.sum(sub_list))
    if a > 0: 
        xx.append(a)
        yy.append(L)
        sub_pos = tuple((pos, pos+L))
        print(tuple(sub_list), sub_pos)
    pos += L
```

For every sequence with positive entries, the variable `sub_pos` is generated (and printed). Just store them instead of/in addition to printing them.

Comment: Hi David
Thank you very much

Comment: @AppolinaireDerbetini Please accept this answer by clicking the green tick under the score so that it can help other people finding this answer more easily.